# What's a way to disable interruptions in program

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know if it exists, but I'd like to disable warnings and pop-ups from interrupting my program.

It's a VR application and full screen, when a pop up (for example from a faulty USB stick that keeps disconnecting and reconnecting) comes up, the application will pause and freeze. This ruins the experience, and I'd like my program to never be interrupted by anything.

Is there a way to do this? It would be best if it could be done using code, so I wouldn't have to set this on every PC my program is installed on. But any other workaround is welcome.

Comment: Unplug the USB stick is probably the easier solution...

Comment: @Charleh: Easy perhaps, but not general?  What do you do about "37 Windows Updates available!" notification?  "Network card unplugged!"  "Network card replugged!", and all the other things affected by things outside your local system.

Comment: Are you running in Exclusive Mode?

Comment: @Charleh Yeah, but I can't expect the end users to think about that. I just want it foolproof

Comment: @MikeMiller Am running it in Exclusive mode, I'm using and Oculus Rift DK 2 (0.7 runtime) for the application

Comment: Sorry was a bit trolltastic that :P Windows is a ball-ache when it comes to stupid bloody popups. If I had a penny for every time a popup interrupted a mouse click I'd be rich!